# How to create game-wide object in Unity3d without singleton?

Tags: unity-game-engine, singleton, game-engine, scene, gameobject

Is there a way in Unity3d framework to register an object  that would be accessible to all entities in all scenes in the game without resorting to singleton pattern (like a game state object)?

Comment: Of course, but you will need to find the reference on every single object that interacts with him

Comment: Why not just use a static class?

Comment: @SwiftingDuster Static classes are not any less singleton-y than singletons.

Comment: It's perfect for OP's aim to store game states. They are fundamentally similar but they do have differences. Maybe you can share your method then?

Comment: @SwiftingDuster static class will not work for me either, because it has very same downsides as singleton which I'm trying to circumvent.

Comment: If that's the case maybe you can share why you are trying to avoid singletons, its probably easier for people to help that way.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the following approach:

In the scene where the GameObject is created, in a MonoBehavior script attached to the GameObject:

- **Name the GameObject with "name = ..." in Awake() (or in the Editor)**

  - Example: *myObject.name = "FindMeInEveryScene";*
  - Ref: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-name.html
- **Call "DontDestroyOnLoad" on the GameObject in Awake()**

  - Example: *DontDestroyOnLoad( myObject );*
  - Ref: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

In the same scene and in subsequent scenes, in MonoBehavior scripts attached to other GameObjects.

- **Find the object with GameObject.Find(...) in Start()**

  - Example: *globalGameObject = GameObject.Find( "FindMeInEveryScene" );*
  - Ref: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html

This will allow you to access the GameObject named "FindMeInEveryScene" without a singleton.

To pull it all together...

**GlobalGameObject.cs**

```
// Attached to the GameObject that needs to be accessd by any other
// GameObjects and needs to survive between loading scenes
public class GlobalGameObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    static bool gameObjectInitialized = false;

    void Awake()
    {
        if ( !gameObjectInitialized )
        {
            gameObject.name = "FindMeInEveryScene";
            DontDestroyOnLoad( gameObject );
            gameObjectInitialized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**UsingGameObject.cs**

```
// Attached to GameObjects that need access to the GlobalGameObject
public class UsingGameObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject globalGameObject = null;

    void Start()
    {
        globalGameObject = GameObject.Find( "FindMeInEveryScene" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do it using events but it isn't really the optimal way to use events.  I'm intrigued to know why a singleton pattern doesn't work for you as this is pretty much their main purpose.

Comment: Singleton will work. The problem is that it goes with trade-offs I would prefer to avoid unless it is absolutely necessary

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't going to do this with a static or a singleton, I don't see any point in you using any kind of game state object in your system design.  It would do the same thing, but slower (avoid GameObject.Find at all costs).  It would lack the guaaranteed uniqueness of the singleton and the easy reference provided by both.  I don't understand what tradeoffs you mean but I'll assume they're sound to try and answer your question.

Doing this without a central game state object is going to require a more decentralized solution.  Tasks that would be performed by a static game manager are now controlled by the individual objects themselves and notified by other objects.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/delegates

The beauty of this method is that objects don't need to know about eachother at all.  They just need to listen for events and notify the system that an event has occured.  I really can't think of another alternative.  Hope this helps.  Best of Luck!