# How to access singleton variables with click and not cause NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this is my Singleton class that initiates E

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    static public Player E;
    public float EA = 5;
    public float EG = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        if (E == null)
        {
            E = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Hero.Awake() - attempted to assign second Hero.S");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        if (EG >= 5 && EA >= 0)
        {
            EG = 0;
        }
        if (EA <= 4 && EG > 9)
        {
            EA = 5;
        }

    }
}
```

now when I'm trying to access it through OnPointerClick() to attempt to modify variables EA and EG in the UseItem() method the system would generate a NullReferenceException. I have tried switching the execution order but did not work. Is it because that I'm trying to modify it? Sorry that I am new to Unity and don't know about these things.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;


public class Slot : MonoBehaviour , IPointerClickHandler

{
    public int ID;
    public string type;
    public string description;
    public bool empty;
    public Texture2D icon;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        useItem();
        Debug.Log("clicked" + transform.name);
    }
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    public void useItem()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (transform.name == "slot(" + (i + 1) + ")")
            {
                Player.E.EA = i;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log(Player.E.EA);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have Player.E never initialized so I it Null. That's whey when you try to access anything on Player.E it gives you NullReferenceExpception. You might want to call `Awake` before accessing `Player.E`.

Comment: https://www.dofactory.com/net/singleton-design-pattern

Comment: https://code-maze.com/singleton/

Comment: Before providing comment/answers please review http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682613/how-to-create-game-wide-object-in-unity3d-without-singleton. Note that one does not control creation of objects in Unity3d the same way as in regular C# application.

Comment: I would advise having names like "E" will cause you issues later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a lazy initializing property but if you really want it to be a Singleton it should go like

```
private static Player _instance;
public static Player E
{
    get
    {
        // if already exists return it directly
        if(_instance) return _instance;

        // otherwise find it in the scene
        _instance = FindObjectOfType<Player>();

        // if found return it
        if(_instance) return _instance;

        // otherwise create it now
        // note that anything you have to configure via the Inspector
        // will not be there so you would need to find another way to 
        // initialize all values
        _instance = new GameObject ("Player").AddComponent<Player>();

        return _instance;
    }
}

private void Awake()
{
    if(_instance && _instance != this)
    {
        // another instance already exists!
        Destroy (gameObject);
        return;
    }

    _instance = this;
}
```

---

Then note that I wouldn't do these in `Update` (every frame)

```
void Update()
{
    if (EG >= 5 && EA >= 0)
    {
        EG = 0;
    }
    if (EA <= 4 && EG > 9)
    {
        EA = 5;
    }
}
```

Rather make `EA` and `EG` also properties and do the check only when you actually change the value:

```
private int _ea = 5;
private int _eg = 0;

public int EA
{
    get => _ea;
    set
    {
        _ea = value;
        if (_eg >= 5 && _ea >= 0) _eg = 0;
        if (_ea <= 4 && _eg > 9) _ea = 5;
    }
}

public int EG
{
    get => _eg;
    set
    {
        _eg = value;
        if (_eg >= 5 && _ea >= 0) _eg = 0;      
        if (_ea <= 4 && _eg > 9) _ea = 5;
    }
}
```

Now every time you set one of these values via e.g.

```
Player.E.EA = i;
```

the according setter is executed and your backing fields updated event driven.

---

And now, yes now it is questionable if you even need this as a `MonoBehaviour` ... actually you do not even need an instance and therefore no Singleton at all!

```
public static class Player
{
    private static int _ea = 5;
    private static int _eg = 0;

    public static int EA
    {
        get => _ea;
        set
        {
            _ea = value;
            if (_eg >= 5 && _ea >= 0) _eg = 0;          
            if (_ea <= 4 && _eg > 9) _ea = 5;
        }
    }

    public static int EG
    {
        get => _eg;
        set
        {
            _eg = value;
            if (_eg >= 5 && _ea >= 0) _eg = 0;
            if (_ea <= 4 && _eg > 9) _ea = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't have to be attached to anything in the scene but is a `static class` which simply "lives" for the entire session as soon as the app is started.

Now simply read and assign e.g.

```
Player.EA = i;
```

---

General note:

Names like `E`, `EA` and `EG` should be avoided! Use more descriptive names! One should know what is ment and what a value stands for by just looking at the name. These shorthands will get you in trouble sooner or later. If you look at your code 6 months later you won't know anymore what `EA` ment in your head ;)

Answer (score 2):

This looks more like a Unity/Monobehavior question than a C# one.
Awake is triggered before the game starts, just once.
It can be treated as an initializer.

As you have a public E, you need to provide an instance to it: by adding an object in Unity IDE interface (drag and drop) or by code.

You can also use Tags instead.
Here you can find more information on how to do it:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html

Comment: No problem.@AustinZhangZZRTheBeasT

Comment: Side note: if you would not show code this would actually answer the question *as asked* (note that @AustinZhangZZRTheBeasT actually don't seem to be interested in Unity3d single instance behavior, but rather standard [singleton])https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton)). Creating second instance on `Awake` guarantees that static instance you have and one that is actually instantiated/used by Unity3d would be different... Just "you need to provide an instance to it: by adding an object in Unity IDE interface (drag and drop) or by code" is enough to get code in the post working.

Answer (score -2):

Modify your code un this line

```
static public Player E;
```

With this code

```
private static Player e;

public static Player E
{
    get
    {
       if(e==null) 
        {
              e= new Player() ;
        } 
       return e;
   } 
    set
    {
      e=value;
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is what the compiler error states after I modified it: "Assets/_Script/Player.cs(33,13): error CS0200: Property or indexer 'Player.E' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Comment: this is not a singleton

Comment: You can **not** use `new` for `MonoBehaviour`!!

Comment: No MonoBehaviour

Comment: @AhmedAli in OP's code in the question it says `public class Player : MonoBehaviour`